# Am wichtigsten usage

Tags: comparative

I wanted to frame a sentence with "Most importantly"

Can I use "Am Wichtigsten ist" or "vor allem sollte"? I am not sure which one is the correct solution.

For example, I want to convey in a letter the below sentence:

> I want an explanation about your delay in two days. **Most
>   importantly** the delivery should not be delayed next week.

Can I frame it like:

> Am wichtigsten ist, es sollen keine Verspätung in kommenden Wochen.

I constructed this sentence on my own and hence please bear with the horrible grammar if any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The English phrase *most importantly* is somewhat fixed, and it translates into the German phrase

> Am wichtigsten ist es, dass sich die Lieferung nächste Woche nicht verzögert.

quite nicely. But you are sending mixed signals here: the previous sentence was very upset (*I want …!*), this one sounds weak in contrast – though it says this is the part most important to you. You should consider writing

> Mir kommt es darauf an, dass sich die Lieferung nächste Woche nicht verzögert.

*Es kommt darauf an* is a fixed phrase meaning *that's the crucial point*.

Comment: Or "Vor allem kommt es mir darauf an..."